# php recursive breadcrumb from MySQL with category names

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, categories, breadcrumbs

Here is my code:

```
function printBreadCrumb($id,$level=0) {

    $levelNames=array('Year','Model','Serie','Maker');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM category  WHERE del=0 AND id=".$id." LIMIT 0,1";
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

      $link = "<a href=\"index.php?parent_id=".$row['parent_id'].
              "\">".$levelNames[$level].":".$row['name']."</a>";

      $bc .= $level==0 ? $link : $link . ' > '  ;
      $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];

      printBreadCrumb($parent_id,$level+1);
    }
    echo $bc."";   
  }
```

The function works fine and I can see the correct category names.
What I want: show into which levelName belongs the item.

eg.: Maker:BMW > Serie:3 > Model:320 > Year:2009

Now my code only works in the deepest cateyory [Year]. If I go up one level I get this:

Serie:BMW > Model:3 > Year:320

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your level param which you pass into function the first time because the code is fine. You should check you function calling. Maybe you always call with $level=0.

Also you should remove while because you always get only one record.
Instead of while you should use simple $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);